# Image generator in Googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

I wonder how I can generate an image, actually a small  circle
with color and number as parameter in Googlemaps?

So for example

MakeImage($FF0000, 5)

Will draw a red circle with number 5 in centre.
What is the best approach without pregenerate all possible 
combinations as image-files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this you can create an icon as [Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Symbol) interface and combine it with [MarkerLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel). Note the presense of the property `labelOrigin` in the Symbol interface, it defines where you will put the label.

To demonstrate this approach I used the built-in SVG path `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE`. Have a look at the following example and run it to see circle Marker with number.

```js
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 47.363362, lng: 8.485823};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!',
      icon: {
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 8,
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0,0)
      },
      label: {
        text: "5",
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        fontSize: "16px"
      }
    });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use custom markers, [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols) you can find a well documented API and it's explained how to make markers with bitmaps and svg graphics. I suggest to use SVG path notation like this:

```
var map;
var my_location = { lat: 12.97, lng: 77.59 };

icon = {
     //this is a string that define a circle path
     path: "M 100, 100 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0",
     //this is a string that defines a hex color
     fillColor: '#FF0000',
     //this is a float that defines the opacity value from 0.0 to 1
     fillOpacity: .6,
     //this is a couple that defines a center point for the SVG
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     //this is a integer that defines the scale factor
};
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91722, 151.23064),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
function makeMarkerWithImageCircle(text,location){
     var iconUrl = 'https://your_circl_image_url.png';
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: text,
          icon: iconUrl,
          map: map
     });
}
function makeMarkerWithSVGCircle(text,location){
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          label: text,
          draggable: false,
          icon: icon,
          map: map
     });
}
//method to generate marker with custom image url and text
makeMarkerWithImageCircle("text",my_location);
//method to generate marker with custom svg and text
makeMarkerWithSVGCircle("text",my_location);
```

I guess you have your `initMap()` method wherein you initialise a Map instance
Then you can make your custom function to instantiate a custom Marker inside the Map `map` with a SVG as your icon property.
I didn't run this script, just wrote to explain how you can do this.
Have a nice day and I hope this was helpful (: